# Server side or Javascript calculations?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

In general is it better for performance to do lots of data calculations on the server side or on the javascript side?

I have a bunch of data that i'm displaying on a page - and I'm wondering if I should format/ parse/ make calculations on that data on the server side (in python) and return a template or if I should return the data as is and do all my calculating/ formatting on the javascript side?

Are there any general rules of thumb when making these decisions?

Examples of things i'm calculating - converting timestamps to dates.

Comment: For something like dates where every user might be in a different time zone, putting it on the client makes your pages more cacheable.

Comment: if you can offload calculations to the user, so much the better. but if the calcs are on a load of data, then you'll have to balance the server cpu time savings v.s. the increased bandwidth costs of sending raw data to the clients.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on what you are trying to do. If the chart is dynamic and animated, doing it client side with js may be the only choice. It also depends on how much data you have. I would not recommend doing it in js if you have over 10mb of raw data.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should consider change you data format for storing a data for displaying. It should be stored already in the convenient way for displaying it - that does not requires any processing at all.

If you still need some recalculation of data consider doing it server-side as this gives you possibility of caching this result (for example in [mamceched](http://memcached.org/)) as this make no sense to calculate them on every page refresh.

The worst option is recalculating them client side, as this can bring hard to detect noticeable performance issues on client browser (eg. on larger data) and you could be unable to see this kind of problem in your testing environment (you could see that your server is slowing down, but it is very hard to see that some clients renders your page very very slow - unless they write to you).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the facts stated by thedk, you should also keep in mind that calculations you do on client side are more likely to fail because the client may not fulfill certain preconditions. Think of disabled JavaScript or an unreliable internet connection. You generally have no control over your data as soon as it has left the server.

So, it would be highly advisable to move only unimportant calculations to the client side. Something like datetime formation might be okay, but don't try to parse your whole website with JavaScript. Your website should work (and look acceptable) even if JavaScript is disabled on the client.